# How to distinguish a quantum superposition from a mixed state (ensemble)? Does a single measurement provide any information?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

I will measure an object that is **either** in a mixed state of $\vert A\rangle$ and $ \vert B \rangle$ **or** a superposition $\vert A\rangle + \vert B\rangle$, and I am trying to find out which.  I have set up the experiment so that:

- If the object is in state $\vert A\rangle$ or $\vert B\rangle$, then either detector $1$ or $2$ will fire with equal likelihood.
- If the object is in superposition $\vert A\rangle + \vert B\rangle$, then **only** detector $2$ will fire.

Of course, if I repeat the experiment many times (and assuming the object was identically prepared) and detector $2$ fires every time, then I can infer that it was in superposition $\vert A\rangle + \vert B\rangle$.

Here's my question: If I do the experiment only **once**, and detector $2$ fires, does that give me any information (or change the likelihood) that the object was in a superposition $\vert A\rangle + \vert B\rangle$?

I assume this has something to do with Bayesian updating, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108873/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-knight-how-to-distinguish-a-quantum-superpositi).

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the original version of the question:

---

Your question is based on a wrong premise altogether: Such a detector setting does not exist (at least if $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are different).

To see why, imagine you either prepare $|A\rangle$ or $|\psi\rangle=|A\rangle+|B\rangle$. Those two states are different and not orthogonal (at least if $|B\rangle$ is normalized and different from $|A\rangle$; if they are orthogonal, choose $|\psi\rangle=|B\rangle$ instead, which then has the same properties).

Now send this state into your detector.  If you chose $|A\rangle$, detector 1 will klick, and if you chose $|\psi\rangle$, detector 2 will klick.

So you have managed to distinguish these two states with certainty.  But they were not orthogonal, and it well known that you cannot unambiguously discriminate two non-orthogonal states with certainty.

Thus, your whole premise is flawed.

Comment: @AndrewKnight Note that changing questions in a way which invalidate previous answers is bad practice.